# How to set SslConfiguration in QT5.9?

Tags: qt, https, openssl, qnetworkaccessmanager

QT5.9.7 vs2017 msvc2017_64

my setting:

```
QSslConfiguration config;
config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1SslV3);
httpRequest.setSslConfiguration(config);

httpRequest.setUrl(QUrl(strUrl));

QEventLoop eventLoop;
QObject::connect(&networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
QNetworkReply *reply = networkAccessManager.post(httpRequest, data);
eventLoop.exec();
QByteArray tmpQBA = reply->readAll();
QString tmpQStr = QVariant(tmpQBA).toString();
```

it get **bad reply:**
[image]

when using burpsuite http proxy, get right reply:
[image]

**right reply**
[image]

so, how to get right reply without burpsuite proxy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to [error](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error) and [sslErrors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#sslErrors) signals to see what goes wrong.

You have selected `Use a self-signed certificate` from Burb Suite GUI. When using a self-signed certificate you usually get `SSL Common Name Mismatch Error` which can be ignored when testing.

On Qt you can [ignore SSL errors in QNetworkReply](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#ignoreSslErrors-1) related to a self-signed certificate as follows (from the doc):

```
QList<QSslCertificate> cert = QSslCertificate::fromPath(QLatin1String("server-certificate.pem"));
QSslError error(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate, cert.at(0));
QList<QSslError> expectedSslErrors;
expectedSslErrors.append(error);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://server.tld/index.html")));
reply->ignoreSslErrors(expectedSslErrors);
// here connect signals etc.
```

When you switch to final certificates in production you must remember to remove "ignore" code to not leave security hole in your software.